# What is etc1tool?

Tags: android, sdk

I've seen the android SDK platform-tools folder has a program named **etc1tool**.

It says it converts PNG files into ETC1, but what is ETC1 file?

I don't understand what is it and when use it.

The help (below), [ubuntu man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man1/etc1tool.1.html), and [android doc](https://developer.android.com/tools/help/etc1tool.html) don't seem to explain it either.

```
$ ./etc1tool --help
./etc1tool infile [--help | --encode | --encodeNoHeader | --decode] [--showDifference difffile] [-o outfile]
    Default is --encode
        --help           print this usage information.
        --encode         create an ETC1 file from a PNG file.
        --encodeNoHeader create a raw ETC1 data file (without a header) from a PNG file.
        --decode         create a PNG file from an ETC1 file.
        --showDifference difffile    Write difference between original and encoded
                                     image to difffile. (Only valid when encoding).
    If outfile is not specified, an outfile path is constructed from infile,
    with the apropriate suffix (.pkm or .png).
```

Note [sic] for "apropriate".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A Compressed Texture. Spec is [here](http://www.khronos.org/registry/gles/extensions/OES/OES_compressed_ETC1_RGB8_texture.txt).

Comment: I can't figure out what the tool's "difffile" is supposed to be useful for. EG if I have a screenshot png, and I make that tiny with tinypng.com it goes from 928K to 312K, the output pkm is as expected identical at 1016K, however the diff for processing either is 1064K or 692K respectively. So the diff isn't related to the original 24bit RGB. And so I can't conceptualize its utility.

Comment: @dlamblin It's likely outputting the difference in pixel values between the input and output images. ETC1 is a lossy format.

Answer (score 1):

Its a tool that compressed the size of your image (If not compressed)
here its a usage of etc1tool

go to terminal

- 1) cd AndroidSDK/platform-tools/
- 2)**./etc1tool** /Users/c68/Desktop/Imgcopy.png

You should get Imgcopy.pkm ,A compreesded version of your image

now we need to decode .PKM file , Use below command to decode your file

1. ./etc1tool --decode /Users/c68/Desktop/imgcopy.pkm

Done!!

You will get your compressed version of the image with same named as **Imgcopy.png**.